# El método DELETE y PUT siempre llaman a POST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, delete

Hola tengo un problema y ya no se como darle más vueltas.

Tengo una ventana que muestra una lista de tipos de actividades en una tabla que carga desde BD. A cada row le tengo puesto varios botones de acción, entre ellos el eliminar y el editar. El problema que me aparece es que cuando le doy a cualqueira de los dos botones, siempre llaman al method POST. Ambos los tengo con el PUT y el DELETE pero no entran por ahí y siempre van al POST.

Pongo el código del controler y del html a ver si alguien ve algo que se me está pasando por alto.

Clase Tipo_Actividad_ServicioController:

```
@Controller
public class Tipo_Actividad_ServicioController {

    @Autowired
    private Tipo_Actividad_ServicioService tipo_Actividad_ServicioServcie;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tipo_actividad_servicio", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String findAll(Model model) {

        extracted(model);

        return "tipo_actividad_servicio";

    }

    // Guardar Tipo_Actividad_Servicio
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tipo_actividad_servicio", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String save(Tipo_Actividad_Servicio tipo_Actividad_Servicio, Model model) {

        tipo_Actividad_ServicioServcie.save(tipo_Actividad_Servicio);
        
        extracted(model);

        return "tipo_actividad_servicio";

    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tipo_actividad_servicio", method = RequestMethod.PUT) 
    public String saveById(@RequestParam int id, Model model) {

        Tipo_Actividad_Servicio tipo_Actividad_Servicio = tipo_Actividad_ServicioServcie.findById(id);
        
        if(tipo_Actividad_Servicio.isActivo())
            tipo_Actividad_Servicio.setActivo(false);
        else
            tipo_Actividad_Servicio.setActivo(true);
        
        tipo_Actividad_ServicioServcie.save(tipo_Actividad_Servicio);

        extracted(model);

        return "tipo_actividad_servicio";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tipo_actividad_servicio", method = RequestMethod.DELETE) 
    public String deleteById(@RequestParam int id, Model model) {

        tipo_Actividad_ServicioServcie.deleteById(id);
        
        extracted(model);

        return "tipo_actividad_servicio";

    }

    private void extracted(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("tipos_actividad_servicio", tipo_Actividad_ServicioServcie.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("tipo_actividad_servicio", new Tipo_Actividad_Servicio());

    }

}
```

Y la tabla del HTML que llama al método delete.

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="familia,iterStat : ${tipos_actividad_servicio}" th:class="${iterStat.odd}? 'odd'">
  <td th:text="${familia.id}" style="display:false"></td>
  <td th:text="${familia.nombre}"></td>
  <td th:text="${familia.tipo}"></td>
  <td th:text="${familia.observaciones}"></td>
  <td style="display: flex; justify-items: center; align-items: center;">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="text-white btn .btn-sm btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-lg">
          Editar
      </button>
      <form style="margin: 0px;" th:action="@{/tipo_actividad_servicio}" th:method="put">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${familia.id}">
        <button class="text-white btn .btn-sm btn-success" th:unless="${familia.activo}" type="submit">
            Activar
        </button>
        <button class="text-white btn .btn-sm btn-secondary" th:if="${familia.activo}" type="submit">
            Desactivar
        </button>
      </form>
      <form style="margin: 0px;" th:action="@{/tipo_actividad_servicio}" th:method="delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${familia.id}">
        <button class="text-white btn .btn-sm btn-danger" th:if="${familia.activo}" type="submit">
            Eliminar
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Esto es lo que me muestra la consola cuando llama al método:

```
Hibernate: update tipo_actividad_servicio set activo=?, nombre=?, observaciones=?, tipo=? where id=?
```

Cuando inspecciono el form desde firefox me dice que el método es post y que va a llamar al PUT o DELETE...

```
<form style="margin: 0px;" action="/tipo_actividad_servicio" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
  <button class="text-white btn .btn-sm btn-secondary" type="submit">
    Desactivar
  </button>
</form>
```

La verdad es que ya no se exactamente que hacer y que probar, si alguien pudiera indicarme porque no elimina...

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví gracias a un compañero de stackoverflow. Solo hay que añadir en el `application.properties` la instrucción:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled = true
```

Muchas gracias a todos igualmente.